# loop to change string (for file import function)

Tags: r

I'm working on some R code to automatize file import. I´ve been using `sub` to change the `path` string, more specifically I want to go through `Trial1` to `Trial10` for participant 1 and so forth and than save it as `data[i]`. Instead of putting this manually for all trials could this be done more efficiently with a loop? The function itself adds the filepath to the imported data so I can use this information later

```
path <- "C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/tapping backup/Pilot141116/pilot_151116_pat1_250/realisations/participant_8/Trial1"

setwd( path )
files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "midi.*\\.csv", full.names = T )

# set up a function to read a file and add a column for filename
import <- function( file ) {
  df <- read_csv( file, col_names = T )
  df$file <- file
  return( df )
}

# run that function across all files.
data1 <- ldply( .data = files, .fun = import )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build the file list from `pilot_151116_pat1_250/realisations/` with `recursive` set to `TRUE` and `full.names` set to `TRUE`. Then you run the `ldply` loop with the `import` function. Later you can deduce from the `file` column which participant and trial you data was part of. This can be done by using `strsplit` with `sep` equal to `/`, or by using `separate` from the `dplyr` package.